# PHP regex, check for a lot of the same letter, continuously

Tags: php, regex

I want to prevent this kind of typing:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbnonsense
```

for that I want to check that a certain letter gets repeated more than 9 times:

```
preg_match('/.{9,}/',$key)
```

but this would suit any word that has more than 9 letters in it, such as: `supercalifregilisticexpealidocious`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a [back reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) to match the same character multiple times:

```
preg_match('/(.)\1{8}/', $string);
```

Comment: And you'll probably want something like `[^-=*\s]` instead of `.`, since whitespace (especially for blank lines) and the other characters are often intentionally repeated.  The exact character set will depend on your audience and what they're entering.